# Heroku Fatal when pushing app to live server

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Attempting to push my app to **heroku**
I get no errors when I run `git push heroku master`
I ran the command from inside the directory under **node** terminal in **VSCode**
I tried to run it from the **bash cml** and I got *Everything up-to-date*
Here are both links to heroku provided me when `heroku create`
**https://weather-app-taylor.herokuapp.com/** and **https://git.heroku.com/vast-shelf-27543.git**
Below is the transaction after entering `git push heroku master`

```
    Enumerating objects: 70, done.
Counting objects: 100% (70/70), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (59/59), done.
Writing objects: 100% (70/70), 991.41 KiB | 1.12 MiB/s, done.
Total 70 (delta 21), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified     
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 12.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.16.1...    
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.13.4
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        added 105 packages from 126 contributors and audited 202 packages in 3.401s
remote:        found 1 low severity vulnerability
remote:          run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        removed 1 package and audited 201 packages in 
1.095s
remote:        found 1 low severity vulnerability
remote:          run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 25.5M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://vast-shelf-27543.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/vast-shelf-27543.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

**Here is the port**
[image]

Here is the script for **Heroku** to run the app.
[image]

I also tried to re-push to heroku with `git push heroku master` which gives me a **fatal**

```
    PS C:\Users\Samson\Documents\JS\node1\wbs2> git push heroku master
remote: !       No such app as vast-shelf-27543.
fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/vast-shelf-27543.git/' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Since I already had the app pushed to Heroku when I initially tried, I simply added

```
heroku git:remote -a appName
```

Then went back and `git push heroku master`